# Get-ADUser always returns 0

Tags: c#, powershell

I have script in PowerShell:

```bsh
Get-ADUser $Login -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed |
    select -expand msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed
```

and I'm trying to import it to C# (WPF), but result/result2 is always 0.
PowerShell script works well and returns informations.

```cs
using (PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PS.AddScript("Get - ADUser");
    PS.AddParameter("Identity", TextBox_UserLoginIn.Text);
    PS.AddParameter("Properties", "msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed");
    PS.AddStatement();
    PS.AddCommand("Select");
    PS.AddParameter("-expand", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed");

    var result = PS.Invoke();

    long result2 = long.Parse(result.ToString());

    DateTime psdata = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(result2);
    _MetroWindow.TextBox_UserPassExpire.Text = psdata.ToString();
}
```

also trying with import activedirectory but result is the same:

```cs
PS.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Name", "activedirectory");
PS.AddCommand("Get - ADUser").AddParameter("Identity", TextBox_UserLoginIn.Text);
PS.AddParameter("Properties", "msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed");
PS.AddStatement();
PS.AddParameter("-expand", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed");
```

**EDIT:**
Trying else:

```
PS.AddScript("import-module activedirectory");
PS.AddScript("Get-ADUser -Identity " + TextBox_UserLoginIn.Text + " -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | select -expand msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed");
```

And result is:

```
result  Count = 1
result2 0
```

Maybe there is a way to receive msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed from "DirectoryEntry" or "PrincipalContext"? I use these 2 classes to take information from AD but I can't access to this.

Comment: Remove `.AddStatement()`, they're one single pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
PS.AddScript("Get-ADUser " + TextBox_UserLoginIn.Text + " -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Select -Expand \"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a typo in the parameter for the properties you seek:

```
PS.AddParameter("Properties", "msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed");
```

should be

```
PS.AddParameter("Properties", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed");
```

i guess

**EDIT**

Which of the two versions are you updating/trying out?

I think the complete thing should be

```
using (PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PS.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Name", "activedirectory");
    PS.AddScript("Get-ADUser");
    PS.AddParameter("Identity", TextBox_UserLoginIn.Text);
    PS.AddParameter("Properties", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed");
    PS.AddStatement();
    PS.AddCommand("Select");
    PS.AddParameter("-expand", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed");

    var result = PS.Invoke();

    long result2 = long.Parse(result.ToString());

    DateTime psdata = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(result2);
    _MetroWindow.TextBox_UserPassExpire.Text = psdata.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. Still return 0.

Comment: I also see spaces in the `PS.AddScript("Get - ADUser");`. There should be no spaces in `Get-ADUser`

Comment: Oh true. I didn't notice it somehow but nothing has changed.

Comment: First version.
`result Count = 0`
`result2 0`